# adminer требует логин и пароль

Tags: phpmyadmin, docker

При попытке зайти на adminer вылезает окно с логином и паролем. Логин по умолчанию root и пароль должен быть пустым, но у меня не получается зайти.
Устанавливаю все через докер линкую вот так

```
docker run --link mysqlserver:db -p 8080:8080 adminer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию админер не пускает без пароля
https://www.adminer.org/en/password/